# What should you check when graphQL's query return's empty data from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, graphql

I'm attempting to translate a Flask api to a graphql server. I can get example code to work with a test mongodb collection but I cannot get my adapted code to work on the real mongodb server. The query always returns an empty data response. What are the steps to debug this code?
[image]

```
const Express = require("express");
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
const {
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLSchema
} = require("graphql");

var app = Express();

Mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/treasure-chess");

//"persons" is the collection 
const GameModel = Mongoose.model("game", {
    black: String,
    white: String
});

const GameType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    //the name field here doesn't matter I guess...
    name: "Game",
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        black: { type: GraphQLString },
        white: { type: GraphQLString }
    }
});

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "Query",
        fields: {
            games: {
                type: GraphQLList(GameType),
                resolve: (root, args, context, info) => {
                    return GameModel.find().exec();
                }
            },
            game: {
                type: GameType,
                args: {
                    id: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
                },
                resolve: (root, args, context, info) => {
                    return GameModel.findById(args.id).exec();
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: "Mutation",
        fields: {
            game: {
                type: GameType,
                args: {
                    firstname: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                    lastname: { type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
                },
                resolve: (root, args, context, info) => {
                    var game = new GameModel(args);
                    return game.save();
                }
            }
        }
    })
});

app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
}));


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening at :3000...");
});
```

Proof that I'm connecting to the right mongodb document:

[image]

More proof:

[image]

I did attempt the comment suggestion only to find that the result was empty...:

```
                    var results = GameModel.find().exec()
                    results.then(game_info =>{
                        console.log(game_info)
                    })
```

Comment: you should check DB response ... `console.log( GameModel.find().exec() );`

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion. Seems like the db response is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after trying a bunch of different searches on stackoverflow. It turns out that mongoose.model assumes that whatever parameter you pass is singular and pluralizes it by default. So I actually had to pass in:

```
const GameModel = Mongoose.model("game", gameSchema, "game");
```

Granted most people probably won't experience this error as they probably named their collections with this in mind, there might be the one odd person who wanted to utilize a different name for their collection OR the plural of the collection is the same singular. I'll leave this up for others, happy coding!